# IsMouseOver Trigger - Unexpected behavior when using Path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm seeing unexpected behavior when I try to trigger based on the IsMouseOver property.


In the code below, the trigger will occur on the Border object when the borders Background property is set, but will trigger on the Path object when the borders background is NOT set.

I've tried setting IsHitTestVisible on the border but that was a no-go.


I'm sure there's a reason for this but I obviously don't know it.
Can someone enlighten me?

```
<Geometry x:Key="RightArrowGeometry">M 0 0 L 3 3 L 0 6 Z</Geometry>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <!-- <Border x:Name="TheBorder" Margin="0"> -->                 <!--TRIGGERS ONLY WHEN THE MOUSE IS OVER THE PATH OBJECT -->
                    <Border x:Name="TheBorder" Margin="0" Background="LightBlue">   <!--TRIGGERS WHEN THE MOUSE IS OVER THE BORDER OBJECT -->
                            <Path 
                                x:Name="ButtonShape"
                                Data="{StaticResource RightArrowGeometry}" 
                                Fill="Black" 
                                Stretch="Uniform">
                            </Path>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" SourceName="TheBorder">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" TargetName="TheBorder"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for the border to trigger the `IsMouseOver` when the background is not set, try setting the Border's Background to `Background="Transparent"`.

In contrast to the default `null` backgroud, this will make a transparent background that still triggers the event. Any mouse input events will only trigger if a background is set to a non-null value.

Comment: Just to elaborate a little as to the *why*, a panel requires a brush or fill to create the area of hittestvisibility to trigger the event. Hence the requirement for a Background property. This is the right answer though so +1

Comment: Yup!
That's the ticket.
I tried setting Background={TemplateBinding} but that only worked if I set the parent's background which was essentially the same problem.
Transparent worked though.

Comment: Still, though... Is there a reason for this?  It seems counterintuitive.

Comment: @kshill - yea, because not every instance of a panel needs to invoke an event. :)